# Shell Scripting : Unable to scp output to log file

Tags: perl, scripting, scp

In My Shell Script I am trying to push the scp output to a log file.Below is the code snippet.On Command line I can see the logs but The scp logs are not pushed into the file .What can be the reason ?

```
FTP_LOG = "Log.txt"
scp -v ${feedFile} ${USER}@${DESTINATION}:inbox >> ${FTP_LOG}
```

Please help me on this as I can see that there are other people who faced the same issue when I google.

The other issue is that the last returned code after scp command doesnt really say if the file transfer was a success.Even when the file transfer fails I get the last return code as indicatng success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-v` outputs to STDERR not STDOUT. You want `2>>` not `>>`

Comment: So the whole command will be as below .right ?                        scp -v ${feedFile} ${USER}@${DESTINATION}:inbox 2> not >> ${FTP_LOG}.Please help me on this as I am new to shell

Comment: Youll want `2>>`, so: `scp -v ${feedFile} ${USER}@${DESTINATION}:inbox 2>> ${FTP_LOG}`. I recommend you `man bash` and look at REDIRECTION for an introduction input redirection basics.

Comment: @Quentin Excllnt .. U hit it on the spot .. Its working now .. Can you plz say the reason why its working .. Also  when u say stdrr what does it mean and what does stdout mean(u mean terminal) ... Cheers

Comment: @whokares: Again, I recommend you learn about redirection. Briefly, each process has (by default) two open file descriptors (1 and 2) which are called stdout and stderr respectively. It is conventional to send normal output to 1 and error or warning output to 2. When redirecting you specify which descriptor or, if you don't, 1 is assumed. So `>>` is the same as `1>>` and means "append stdout", whereas `2>>` means "append stderr"

Comment: @Sorpigal .. yes just started learng .. Now you said error or warning output to 2  ..but then why scp succes logs are gng to the file whne we place 2>>.only error or wanrng info shud go right ?

Comment: @whokares: Anything `scp` writes to stderr will go, whether it's error or warning data or not. Anything not written to stderr won't go. If you want both stderr and stdout to go to the file then you need to redirect one into the other first.

Comment: @Sorpigal How to redirect one into other ?

Answer (score 0):

The best aproch IMHO is to redirect stdout and stderr in 2 files, like that :

```
ftp_log=log
ftp_error_log_err_log
scp -v "$feedFile" $USER@${destination}:inbox > "$ftp_log" 2> "$ftp_error_log"
```

Comment: Can you plz explain this part inbox > "$ftp_log" 2> "$ftp_error_log"
  what does it do ?

Comment: The default redirect in the shell is STDOUT (file-descriptor 1), so there's a redirect of STDOUT to $ftp_log. STDERR is file-descriptor 2, there's a redirection of STDERR in $ftp_error_log. For your information, the STDIN file-descriptor is 0. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor